# Python rsync to copy the logs from multiple remote servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-file-transfer, ssh

I have the below code which i'm working to copy(using rsync) the contents From remote host `labserver01` and dumps those into the directory `/var/log/infoSec/` on the base system from where scripts runs and this works correctly and sends e-mail to the recipients, However i'm also figuring out to include a way to send e-mail even if it fails.

I'm Just wondering if there is better way do this, i'm sure there will be more elegant ways.

Appreciate any idea and review in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import subprocess
import argparse
import sys
import os

#Dir Structure
dest_dir = "/infralogs/external_dns_logs"
rsync_user = "root"

email_sender = "dnslogger@udalt.com"
email_receiver = "gusain@udalt.com"
msg = ""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n","--hosts",dest="hosts",help="enter remote host/hosts name, comma seperated",metavar="HOSTS")
parser.add_argument("-s","--src",dest="source",help="source file/directory",metavar="SOURCE")
parser.add_argument("-e","--exclude",dest="exclude",help="Exclude files/Directories, comma seperated list",metavar="EXCLUDE")

if len(sys.argv) < 7:
    print(len(sys.argv))
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()

args = parser.parse_args()

def sync(host,dest_dir):
    exclude = ""
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.mkdir(dest_dir)
    if ',' in args.exclude:
        for excl in args.exclude.split(','):
            exclude = exclude + " --exclude " + excl
        cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dest_dir)
    else:
        cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz --exclude %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(args.exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dest_dir)
    cmd_content = cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    p.wait()
    print("DONE")
    return cmd_content + " Rsync process completed."  # returns the msg to the caller

msglist = []             # a list to store the cmd_contents for the mail body

if ',' in args.hosts:
    for host in args.hosts.split(','):
        dest = dest_dir + "/" + host
        msglist.append(sync(host,dest))
else:
    dest = dest_dir + "/" + args.hosts
    msglist.append(sync(args.hosts,dest))

msg = "\n".join(msglist)                 # combine all cmd_contents, one per line


try:
    Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.udalt.com', 25, 'localhost.udalt.com')
    mail_obj = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    mail_obj["From"] = email_sender
    mail_obj["To"] = email_receiver
    mail_obj["Cc"] = "gusain@udalt.com"
    mail_obj["Subject"] = "Rsync process completed Successfully."
    mail_obj.attach(MIMEText(msg, 'plain'))
    Mail.sendmail(from_addr=[email_sender], to_addrs=[email_receiver],msg=mail_obj.as_string())
    print("Mail Sent to %s" % (email_sender))
except Exception as error:
    print("Mail Failed - {}".format(error))
```

**Command Execution method:**

> `$ /usr/bin/dns_rsync.py  -n labserver01 -s /var/log/infoSec/ -e "null"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Review

1. Constants should be `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`
2. More (and better) functions!

   - Lot of this code is in the global namespace, which is bad (not maintainable)
   - Why is `sync` doing argument parsing?

     You should split up your code into individual instructions

     Same goes for the logic of hosts splitting, these really should be part of another function (maybe `parse_arguments`)
3. Go with [new style formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#2-new-style-string-formatting-strformat) or [fstrings python3.6+](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36)
4. Simplify the `split(',')` using `join()`
5. Don't do manual path appending but use `os.path.join()`
6. Top it off with a `if __name__ == '__main__'`

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import subprocess
import argparse
import os

DEST_DIR = "/infralogs/external_dns_logs"
RSYNC_USER = "root"

EMAIL_SENDER = "dnslogger@udalt.com"
EMAIL_RECIEVER = "gusain@udalt.com"
EMAIL_CC = "gusain@udalt.com"

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-n","--hosts", dest="hosts", help="enter remote host/hosts name, comma seperated", metavar="HOSTS")
    parser.add_argument("-s","--src", dest="source", help="source file/directory", metavar="SOURCE")
    parser.add_argument("-e","--exclude", dest="exclude", help="Exclude files/Directories, comma seperated list", metavar="EXCLUDE")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.exclude is None or args.source is None or args.hosts is None:
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()

    args.exclude = " --exclude " + " --exclude".join(args.exclude.split(','))
    args.hosts = args.hosts.split(',')
    return args.hosts, args.source, args.exclude

def sync(hosts, src, exclude):
    for host in hosts:
        host = host.strip()
        dest = os.path.join(DEST_DIR, host)
        cmd = f"rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz {exclude} {RSYNC_USER}@{host}:{src} {dest}/"
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
        p.wait()
        yield f"{cmd} Rsync process completed."

def mail(message):
    try:
        Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.udalt.com', 25, 'localhost.udalt.com')
        mail_obj = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        mail_obj["From"] = EMAIL_SENDER
        mail_obj["To"] = EMAIL_RECIEVER
        mail_obj["Cc"] = EMAIL_CC
        mail_obj["Subject"] = "Rsync process completed Successfully."
        mail_obj.attach(MIMEText(msg, 'plain'))
        Mail.sendmail(from_addr=[EMAIL_SENDER], to_addrs=[EMAIL_RECIEVER],msg=mail_obj.as_string())
        print(f"Mail Sent to {EMAIL_SENDER}")
        print(message)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Mail Failed - {error}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(DEST_DIR):
        os.mkdir(DEST_DIR)

    for msg in sync(*parse_arguments()):
        mail(msg)
```

Comment: @ Ludisposed, thanks for the review , this looks awesome and i'll borrow the suggestions and code styles as mentions, i'm reading on the reviewed code.